# What's the best way for an Android app to listen for incomming TCP/IP messages?

Tags: android, service, notifications, ip, listen

I want to write an app that will listen for alarm messages whenever it is in the range of a server (on the same WiFi network).  What is the best way to do this?

Should I simply write a service that will act as a TCP/IP server and when it receives messages, have them generate an Android notification?  or is there a better way to do this?

I need this app to be running all the time while Android is running.
How would I ensure that my 'listener' service is always running?

thanks in advance..

Levster

Comment: It will drain battery. Use C2DM...